# Take Picture with Alcatel Pop C5

Tags: android, camera

I experiment problem taking picture with Alcatel Pop C5.
I start Intent with:

```
String picName = "CaptureIni_1441734079";
// photoFile --> storage/sdcard0/Pictures/CaptureIni_1441734079.jpg
File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), picName);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
((Activity) ctx).startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_PIC_INI_REQUEST);
```

This is the way it is mentionned in documentation:
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Camera starts, I take pic and then I get the option to accept pic or not.
Thing is I can't accept it ( clicking OK doesn't do anything )

When I make a debug, Code never goes in OnActivityResult.

It happens with 10 cels POP C5, not for all C5 I have.
Also, I can confirm that camera is working well.

What is going on??? Code works fine with Samsung, also with Alcatel Idol 2 mini, and several Pop C5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are running into a bug with that camera app. Camera app developers, particularly for pre-installed camera apps, rarely test `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` very well.

That being said, I recommend that you change this:

```
File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + picName);
```

to this:

```
File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), picName);
```

This handles the case where `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` returns a value with a trailing path separator. It's possible that this is what is happening to you and will clear up compatibility with this device, but I am not hopeful that it will, and there will be other devices that will cause problems.

Comment: I changed the photofile, but still doesn't working. What do you recommend I should do to get it working?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: "What do you recommend I should do to get it working?" -- um, smash the phone to bits with a hammer? I doubt that there is anything that you can do -- as I wrote, this is probably a bug in the camera app. You can use `Build` values to try to detect this device, then see what camera app you would get from `startActivityForResult()` by means of `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. If you are on this device, and the only camera app is the buggy one, prompt the user to download some other camera app.

Comment: :( I will mark your response as accepted, as you just took away my hopes of a better future !!!

Comment: Other solution would be to develop my own Camera Activity, is it correct?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: Yes. That is not particularly easy.

Comment: It seems that the problem occurs when Cel has a SD Card inside, don't really understand why

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro: I can't explain that. Since you are not pointing the app to a file on removable storage, the app should not care if there is or is not an SD card.

Comment: Also, some users doesn't have Pictures folder, also a cause for failure.